# Select node based on other node attribute (if contains)

Tags: xml, xpath

Hello can anyone help me how to do folowing in the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <details>
        <signature id="sig1">
            <name>mr. Barry Smith</name>
            <telephone type="fixed">01234 123456</telephone>
            <telephone type="mobile">071234562</telephone>
        </signature>

        <signature id="sig2">
            <name>mr. Harry Smith</name>
            <telephone type="fixed">01234 123456</telephone>
        </signature>
    </details>
```

I find answer on "How can I find the names of people who have a mobile phone" `/details/signature[telephone/@type = 'mobile']/name`, - if i include full attribute value, but how could i include contains function in this.
I tried:

```
/details/signature[telephone/[contains(@type,'mobile')]/name
```

but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably:

```
/details/signature[telephone[contains(@type, 'mobile')]]/name
```

looking for a `signature` that has a `telephone` with a `type` attribute which value contains "mobile", and selecting the name child element of this `signature`

```
/details/signature[  telephone[  contains(@type, 'mobile')  ]  ]/name
```

Comment: ok, can you tell me how it would be if i have one child under telephone i.e tr and then telephone type.  i would like something like  /details/signature[tr[0]/telephone[contains(@type, 'mobile')]]/name, then it wont work

Comment: Try `/details/signature[.//telephone[contains(@type, 'mobile')]]/name`

Comment: Tried that, but it seems contains function cant be implemented in this way? Am i right?

Comment: It should work. Can you post another example XML with this last use case?